# Verify string in MVC validator using regularexpressions

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to grasp the concept of Regular Expressions but seem to be missing something.

I want to ensure that someone enters a string that ends with .wav in a field.  Should be a pretty simple Regular Expression.

I've tried this...
[RegularExpression(@"$.wav")]
but seem to be incorrect.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is the anchor for the end of the string, so `$.wav` doesn't make any sense. You can't have any characters after the end of the string. Also, `.` has a special meaning for regex (it just means 'any character') so you need to escape it.

Try writing

```
\.wav$
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
.*\.wav$
```

(It depends on if the `RegularExpression` attribute wants to match the whole string, or just a part of it. `.*` means 'any character, 0 or more times')

Another thing you should consider is what to do with extra whitespace in the field. Users have a terrible habit of adding extra white space in inputs - its why various `.Trim()` functions are so important. Here, `RegularExpressionAttribute` might be evaluated before you can trim the input, so you might want to write this:

```
.*\.wav[\s]*$
```

The `[\s]*` section means 'any whitespace character (tabs, space, linebreak, etc) 0 or more times'.

You should read a tutorial on regex. It's not so hard to understand for simple problems like this. When I was learning I found this site pretty handy: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Great Thanks... turned out to be this...[RegularExpression(@".*wav$")]

Comment: @zenacity note that `.*wav$` is matching strings that end in `wav`, not `.wav` as you specify in your question.